# strapi v4 in admin auth page cannot update helmet title

Tags: node.js, content-management-system, strapi, nuxt-strapi

want to change the Strapi Admin into my custom name but in strapi v3 we have the option to modify in the helmet title inside the AuthPage folder but i can't do it same in the strapi v4.
[image]

list of available translations

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/main/packages/core/admin/admin/src/translations/en.json

thanks in advance

i have tried modified transaction like "AuthPage.helmet.title": "Login - my website",but still it's doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "AuthPage.helmet.title" is not an entry defined in the [available translations](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/main/packages/core/admin/admin/src/translations/en.json) .

You can change your title through /src/admin/app.js :

```
config: {
    ...
    translations: {
      en: {
        "Auth.form.welcome.title": "Welcome to My test App V2 !",
        "Auth.form.welcome.subtitle": "Log in to My test App V2",
      },
    }
}
```

https://forum.strapi.io/t/how-to-change-title-in-login-page/19960

[image]

Comment: but it's not working

Comment: is the picture I uploaded what you want to do? i tested it just few minutes ago. BTW, in your previous config, the title and subtitle remained unchanged.

Comment: what's the command you used to run strapi ?